# What's up with the "Meaning of MIT license"? (5 years old post recently migrated from SO to Programmers meta, then to main)

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

What's up with the [Meaning of MIT license](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/255227/31260)?

This five years old post was recently migrated from SO to Programmers. Not that I complain, but regular migrations like that are blocked by system (see [Disable migration for questions older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/165773)). What makes this question special to overrule this limitation?

I briefly checked recent posts at [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and found nothing about this migration.

---

[Question revision history at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/706799/revisions) shows couple funny changes made recently:

> ```
>     Post Deleted by Tim Post♦   occurred 5 hours ago
>     Post Locked by Community♦   occurred 5 hours ago
>     Post Migrated Away to programmers.stackexchange.com by Tim Post♦
>         occurred 5 hours ago
>     Post Closed as "off-topic" by Tim Post♦     occurred 5 hours ago
>     Post Undeleted by Tim Post♦     occurred 5 hours ago
>     Post Reopened by Tim Post♦  occurred 5 hours ago
>     Migration Rejected  occurred 5 hours ago
>     Post Unlocked by Community♦     occurred 5 hours ago
>     Post Deleted by Shog9♦  occurred 19 hours ago
>     Post Locked by Community♦   occurred 19 hours ago
>     Post Migrated Away to meta.programmers.stackexchange.com by Shog9♦
>         occurred 19 hours ago
>     Post Closed as "off topic" by Wouter J, egrunin, msmucker0527, Mario, Linger
>         occurred Mar 6 '13 at 20:37
> ```

<sup>FWIW it looks like a duplicate of [MIT vs. BSD vs. Dual License](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/121998/31260) to me.</sup>

Comment: `Post Migrated Away to meta.programmers.stackexchange.com by Shog9♦` O_O

Comment: seems a bit like left hand vs. right hand problem, Shog migrated to meta.P.SE where it got rejected and then Tim migrated to P.SE

Comment: @ratchetfreak yeah. Though I am most intrigued by why these guys decided to overrule 60-days limitation to migrate this question

Comment: We've brought this question to the attention of the parties involved, but so far have had no feedback.

Comment: possibly related: [Bug when mod migrating - very easy to migrate to a site's Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277122/165773)